# This в функции ссылается разные объекты

Tags: javascript

Есть html документ, в котором есть один `div id="target"`

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="target"></div>

</body>
```

Для него создан прототип `testMethods`, который содержит специальный набор методов для этого `div`

```
var testMethods = {}
testMethods.__proto__ = HTMLDivElement;
target.__proto__ = testMethods;
```

`testMethods` содержит метод `hello`, который должен добавить элемент `span` к объекту `target`

```
testMethods.hello = function (){

    let textElement = document.createElement('span');
    textElement.textContent = "Hello world!";
    console.log(this); /*Выводит в консоль объект target, то что мне и надо:   <div id="target"></div>*/
    this.appendChild(textElement); /*Ошибка: typeError: this.appendChild is not a function. Ссылается на testMethods*/ 


}
```

Почему this в данном случае ссылается на разные объекты? Как мне правильно прикрепить потомка `span` к родителю `target` через функцию? Правильная ли у меня идея  о том, чтобы через прототипы придать дополнительный фукнционал отдельным DOM элементам у меня на странице? Спасибо.

Comment: c чего ты взял, что _Ссылается на testMethods_? Добавь пример как ты вызываешь эту функцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в неверной установке прототипа.

Чтобы приведенный код заработал, прототипом должен быть **объект** имплементирующий интерфейс [`HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement). В данном же случае в качестве прототипа устанавливается сама *функция*, у которой действительно нет указанного свойства.

Для решения достаточно заменить строку

```
testMethods.__proto__ = HTMLDivElement;
```

На

```
testMethods.__proto__ = target.__proto__;
```

В которой в прототип `testMethods` записывается *уже существующий* прототип `target`.

Пример:

```js
var testMethods = {}
testMethods.__proto__ = target.__proto__;
target.__proto__ = testMethods;

testMethods.hello = function() {

  let textElement = document.createElement('span');
  textElement.textContent = "Hello world!";
  this.appendChild(textElement); 
}

target.hello();
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Идея в том, чтобы к некоторым DOM-элементам прикрутить дополнительный функционал, при этом сохранить стандартные методы. Я в своей реализации иду в правильном направлении?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov, ну вообще не очень. Более красивым может стать наследование от элементов. Либо создание функции, в которую элемент будет передаваться. Но тут все зависит от конкретной задачи.

Comment: Скажем, есть 10 div-контейнеров, к ним нужно прикрутить функции заполнения стандартным набором span-элементов, изменения текстового содержимого/классов этих span-элементов, их приведения к дефолтному виду + вложенные функции для всего этого.

Comment: @IgorCheglakov, а зачем к ним что-то прикручивать? :) Как минимум два варианта: сделать класс в котором будет поле с контейнером, и его методы будут работать с контейнером как с полем. Сделать свой собственный html-элемент и и добавить туда нужные функции.